# Is the pipe which drains water out of the air-conditioner unit a Bossis L'davar Assur, because the water in it is Nolad B'shabbos?

Tags: halacha, shabbat, water, muktzeh

Is the plastic pipe which drains the condensation water out of the air-conditioner unit a "[Bossis L'davar Assur](http://halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Bosis), because the water inside it is [*Nolad B'shabbos*](https://www.ou.org/torah/halacha/hashoneh-halachos/sun_06_23_13/)?

If the whole pipe is either vertically positioned or at least on a sharp incline, would it still be considered a *Bossis*?

If the water is constantly *flowing through* the pipe and not standing still on the interior of the pipe, would that have an affect on the *Bossis* status of the pipe?

Comment: Why isn't there a site policy stating that downvoters must explain the reason for their downvote, so the OP can make necesarry improvements to his question? I think this would benefit the site very much.

Comment: https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/144/commentless-downvotes

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the water being Nolad, see מנחת שלמה חלק ב' סי' ל"ד אות כ"ט where he says it is clear that the water is nolad.

Regarding the plastic pipe, it would seem to be a question only according to the first opinion in  סי' ש"ט סעיף ד about a bosis that will be removed on Shabbos [by a goy or a child]. The first opinion says it is a bosis, so your question would be, where it is being removed automatically does that change. According to the second opinion that it is not a bosis even if it won't go off by itself, your case when it empties itself would definitely not be a bosis. 
The Mishneh Berurah (319/21) relies on the second opinion in the case of a loss.

Also, see עטרת שלמה קובץ זכרון תשס"ה pg. פז-פט where Rav Shlomo Zalman Grossman the Rov of Elad address this question.

Assuming that a 45 degree is not considered "on" an item, your point that "maybe only something ON something else can cause bossis", is like the ב"ח סי' ש"ח (סעיף ט"ז) ד"ה חלוק. However, the (פרי מגדים (סי' ש"ח משבצות זהב ס"ק י"ד says that even if the supporting item is above the Muktza it has the rules of a Bosis.

Comment: I knew that the water is nolad. My question was whether it causes the pipe to be a bossis. When I  asked about the water flowing through it, I wasn't thinking of the idea of a bossis being removed doing shabbos, on the contrary, it is possible that there will be water flowing through the pipe during all of shabbos. My question was if flowing water creates a bossis in the first place, since it is not stationed  on the pipe but flowing. I would have the same question if there was a muktzah ball rolling back and forth over a table would that make the table a bossis?

Comment: This was the same idea in addressed by my question about an inclined bipe, since the muktzah inside is not ON the pipe because it is at a (more than 45 degree) angle, and maybe only something ON something else can cause bossis. Based on all this, I'm sorry to say, your information, as enlightening as it is, as it is, does not answer my question.

Comment: @RibbidRabbiAnd More - It would seem that one reason flowing water should not be a bosis, is because there is no intention for it to remain there the entire Shabbos. Which is why the Mishneh Berurah would seem like the correct reference.  As far as "water flowing through the pipe the entire Shabbos", your point would be good only if all the water is considered one unit.   Your point that the water "is always flowing" and therefore not a bosis, is what Rav Grossman says at least at one point, and why it was referenced. Regarding the water being nolad, I was just trying to source it.

Comment: There is intention for there to be water in the pipe the entire shabbos, since he wants it to be constantly draining the condensation from the unit.

Comment: @RibbidRabbiAnd More - Does the water drain without a break, even for second? It probably depends on the unit.

Comment: You should add the part about the inclined pipe and the בח  and the pri megadim into your answer.

Answer (score 0):

@פרי זהב answer is well founded, and I also heard R' Yitzahk Yossf (if I remember right) on the radio giving a similar opinion, but I want to challenge this viewpoint.

שבת קכא ב

> וַהֲלֹא הִיא עַצְמָהּ מוּכֶנֶת לִכְלָבִים! וְכִי תֵּימָא דְּלָא
> חַזְיָא לֵיהּ מֵאֶתְמוֹל — וְהָתַנְיָא: נְהָרוֹת הַמּוֹשְׁכִין
> וּמַעֲיָינוֹת הַנּוֹבְעִין — הֲרֵי הֵן כְּרַגְלֵי כׇּל אָדָם.

Shabbat 121:b

The [toddler's] feces themselves prepared as food for dogs [therefore not *muktze*]! And if you say these feces were not prepared for that use from yesterday [therefore *nolad*], wasn’t it taught in a baraita: With regard to rivers that flow and springs that gush, they do not have specific Shabbat boundaries, but they may be used anywhere and their boundaries are like the feet of all people who draw from them.

So, water comes from the AC is ***WAY*** more similar to "rivers that flow and springs that gush" then toddler's feces, and should be allowed to use on Shabat, which makes the pipe basis (why "bosis"?) *Ladavar Hamuter*.

Comment: I'm not a Rabbi, so you can't practically relay on my answer. Consult your rabbi.